# Why do I get error when try to convert Carbon to DateTime?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, phpstan

I am developing a Laravel project. I try to create a DateTime object by using Carbon. This is what I tried:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2021-10-01T00:01:00')->toDateTime();
```

But my phpstan complains : `Cannot call method toDateTime() on Carbon\Carbon|false.`

Why is this error? What is the correct way to convert `Carbon` to a `DateTime` object?

Comment: The time you've supplied is not in the format you told Carbon to expect.  So `createFromFormat()` fails, probably returning false.

Comment: @Don'tPanic but that's something that PHPStan cannot detect

Comment: `Y-m-d H:i:s` versus `2021-10-01T00:01:00`. Your format has a space; your string has a T instead. Your date string doesn't match your expected format.

Comment: @ceejayoz that's something that PHPStan cannot detect through static analysis

Comment: @NicoHaase Well, OP's code as-written throws an exception. They should fix that first, if nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, of course. But as far as I see, this question is about static analysis, not about any runtime error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your format is incorrect, so Carbon cannot create the time. You're missing the T, which needs to be escaped.

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', '2021-10-01T00:01:00')->toDateTime();
```

Comment: Please share more details. If PHPStan threw that initial error, what makes you think that your code works different?

Comment: Tried, doesn't help.

Comment: What about it doesn't help? It works for me. Though as ceejayoz said in his answer, Carbon is already a DateTime object, and can be used as such. Check out the [documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for all of the extra features over DateTime.

Comment: @NicoHaase Because I tested it out. When I used `Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', '2021-10-01T00:01:00')->toDateTime();` in Tinker, I got a DateTime object with `date: 2021-10-01 00:01:00.0 America/New_York (-04:00),`. However, I'm not familiar with PHPStan.

Comment: Did you test out whether your change resolves the warning thrown by PHPStan? Or did you only run the code, which does not trigger any checks through PHPStan?

Comment: I don't use PHPStan, so I'm not familiar with it. This only fixes the formatting error.

Comment: Sorry, it was another chained error, your answer is actually the solution for my question.

Answer (score 2):

If PHPStan complains, that's because the static analysis (which does not execute the code) cannot determine the types properly. As Carbon extends `DateTime`, the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) can help for this method call:

> Returns a new DateTime instance or false on failure.

So, to ensure that the code is sound in terms of static analysis, you need to split it up:

```php
$object = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2021-10-01T00:01:00');

if (!$object instanceof Carbon) {
  throw new RuntimeException('could not parse date');
}

$object->toDateTime();
```

The difference: now, PHPStan can safely assume that `$object` is of type `Carbon` when `toDateTime()` is called

---

As others pointed out: **running** that code would also yield an error, as the date format you try to parse from and the input date do not match. But that is out of scope for PHPStan, which does **not** execute the code

Answer (score 0):

Carbon objects are *already* DateTime objects.

```
class Carbon extends \DateTime
```

You may want `toDateTimeString`, but if you really want a DateTime object, you've already got one, just with a little Carbon syntax sugar sprinkled on top.

If you *really* need a DateTime object, the `->toDate()` function is what you're looking for.

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

> Return native DateTime PHP object matching the current instance.

Comment: Yep, I know it is a wrapper of DateTime, but I tried what I posted, it yields error. also tried `->toDate()`, still get phpstan error: Cannot call method `toDate()` on `Carbon\Carbon|false`.  Have you tried the code? Does it really work for you?

Comment: @user842225 Well, you've told it to expect `Y-m-d H:i:s`, but you've provided `Y-m-d\TH:i:s` formatted data. The text you're giving Carbon doesn't match the format you say it's in.